# Symfony custom constraint to Reset Password function form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, constraints

I have implemented a password reset page to my project. It is working, but i try to use best practices and reusable code. So here is the problem.
I have a FormType for the Password Reset form and a Resetting Controller. 
I know that validating normally means mapping the fields of the form type to an object of a class and having validation rules on the properties of this object. 
But for the password reset, i think using "non mapped" fields is required. For now, i submit the form and get the values in the ResettingController. There i check by myself if a user with the email, birthday and security answer exists. This is working but i think not implemented the right way.
Is it possible to add a custom constraint to the whole ResetFormType and when submitting the form, it should call the constraint which checks if the user exists. So i want to use the Symfony Validation system, not the "if, else , if..." that i wrote in the controller.

**Here is my code:**

ResetPwFormType:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('username', null, array(
                'label' => 'resetting.request.username',
                'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add('birthday', 'date', array(
                'years' => range(date('Y') - 74, date('Y') - 18),
                'label' => 'register.user.contact.birthdayBlank',
                'translation_domain' => 'Startup',
                 'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add('plainSecurityAnswer', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'register.user.security.answer',
                'translation_domain' => 'Startup',
                 'mapped' => false
            ));
}
```

ResettingController:

```
        $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new ResetPwFormType());
        $form->handleRequest($this->container->get('request'));

        $username = $form->get('username')->getData();
        $birthday = $form->get('birthday')->getData();
        $securityAnswer = $form->get('plainSecurityAnswer')->getData();

        /** @var $user UserInterface */
        $user = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findUserForPasswordReset($username, $birthday, $securityAnswer);

        $jsonReturn = array();

        if($user !== null)
        {
          // etc.
        }
```

I'd like to use here the "$form->isValid()" method, not saving each field of the form in a variable, passing it to the repository method and checking there if user exists manually. And for that, i think a constraint for the whole form is required ..?

Update: I think i need a model class for the reset process, and to this whole class, i can add a custom validation constraint.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'constraints' option in form builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username', null, array(
            'label' => 'resetting.request.username',
            'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new YourCustomConstraint()
            ]
        ));
}
```

Comment: Ok and this Constraint is then added to the "Model" class that i create for the ResetProcess. Right ?

Comment: Via this constraint you could validate value in 'username' field. Not necessarily add it to "Model" class

Answer (score -1):

I implemented now a "Model" class for the reset form type. There i can add constraints to the properties (username, birthday, securityAnswer) and then additionally add a constraint to the class itself.

Comment: Why is this "-1" ? It is the official, best way to handle that ?! If you are not informed, don't rate that down.